# Fancybox v2 Scroll Up on Mobile Device

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am Fancybox v2.1.5. The issue i am facing is on mobile devices when scroll down and click on any popup. The popup opens on top of the page, which make no sense.

```
    jQuery('.fancy_dialogue').fancybox({
     minWidth  : '60%',
     maxWidth  : '75%',
     autoSize: false, // shouldn't be true ?
     fitToView: false,      
   });
```

I want wherever the link is tapped should open the popup exact on the same place, in center.

Okay Just in case anyone went through this issue. I have resolved it this way for mobile and it worked for me

```
jQuery('.fancy_ajax_close_btn').fancybox({
    minWidth  : '43%',
    maxWidth  : '60%',
    afterLoad : function() {

        var top = ($(window).height() / 2) - ($(".fancybox-wrap").outerHeight() / 2);
        var left = ($(window).width() / 2) - ($(".fancybox-wrap").outerWidth() / 2);
        $(".fancybox-wrap").css({ top: top, left: left});           
    }           

});
```

Just added three lines in afterLoad event and change in jquery.fancybox.css

```
.fancybox-wrap {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 8020;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I would suggest to upgrade to v3, because v2 is not optimized for mobile devices.

Comment: I tried updating it to V3, but in V3 there are alot of changes. They have changed the overall way of calling the popups and syntax. The reason I am not able to change it in my whole website. Everything work great in V2, except the one i am facing it right now

Comment: It is quite easy to upgrade, for example, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47637766/fancybox3-trigger-an-iframe If you have any trouble, you can ask for help.

Comment: o Wow, thank you. I already have planned to use a new version in my next project and your link will definitely going to help me out.

Comment: I updated my response in here. I found one solution not the perfect one though but it worked for me to adjust the position after Load function.